# cannot parse the String to Date object

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I have a String in this format : `2016-08-08T10:27:06.282858+00:00`.

I want to parse this string to get the Date object. 
I tried

`SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");`

But I'm getting the error: `Unparseable date: "2016-08-08T11:06:22+00:00" (at offset 19)`

I tried every other format in place of 'Z' as 'X', 'XXX' but nothing seems to work.

Comment: use like this

`SimpleDateFormat sourceDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd)`
you'll be able to parse the `date object` by doing this

Comment: @NitinMisra I wanted to sort complete String to get the total milli seconds in the date.

Comment: @duffymo I couldn't solve my problem with the solution present in the thread you attached as duplicate.

Comment: I've removed the duplicate.  Let's see if we can do better.

Comment: @Ran94 look at the tile of the question `cannot parse the String to Date object`

Answer (score 0):

Correct format is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX". ' ' is used to escape simbols and avoid parsing them.

Answer (score 0):

the `'Z'` at the end of your pattern seems to be the problem. I removed it and parsing worked:

```
@Test
public void testParsing() throws Exception {
    String text = "2016-08-08T10:27:06.282858+00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");

    Date date = df.parse(text);
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

Output:

```
Mon Aug 08 10:31:48 CEST 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ran94 You're trying to parse a wrong date i.e **2016-08-08T11:06:22+00:00** and seems invalid, the correct possible value for this should be `2016-08-08T11:06:22+0000` which can be represented by this format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`. Hope this helps